# Check if a mesh has an UV Channel in Python

Tags: python

I want to create a script that checks if the selected mesh has an UV Channel, if not it does a Smart UV Project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
import bpy

# Check if active object has any UV layers
if not len( bpy.context.object.data.uv_layers ):
    bpy.ops.uv.smart_project() # Perform smart UV projection
```

Comment: Thank you! Also we don't need to enter in edit mode to do a smart project with scripts.

Comment: Well I'll be, you're right - I'll fix the code above.